# Download node 8.17.0 via gradle ONLY If the node is not installed in the system

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

Code in build.gradle:

```
node {
    version = '8.17.0'
    download = true
}

plugins{
    id "com.moowork.node" version "1.3.1"
}
```

I added the task below to get the installed node version and made the npm task depends on that task, and using stdout value in deciding whether to download the node or not, but the node block containing 'download = true' gets executed before everything and tries to download the node every time.

```
task execute(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'node', '-v'
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    Set s = standardOutput.collect()
    ext.stdout =  {return s.getAt(0).toString()}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Gradle build has [three distinct phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases): initialization, configuration, and execution. The `node { download = true }` gets executed during the configuration phase, whereas the body of your `execute` task gets executed during the execution phase.

To compute the result during the configuration phase, you should change your `execute` task to an ordinary Groovy function:

```
bash-3.2$ cat build.gradle
ext {
  nodeVersion = getNodeVersion()
}

def getNodeVersion() {
  def baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  def execResult = project.exec {
    commandLine 'node', '-v'
    standardOutput = baos
  }
  return baos.toString();
}

task printNodeVersion {
  doLast {
    println(project.nodeVersion)
  }
}
bash-3.2$ ./gradlew :printNodeVersion

> Task :printNodeVersion
v13.12.0


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 566ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Here I store the node version in the extension object `ext` during *configuration* time and I print the value in the `printNodeVersion` task during *execution* time.

For your use case, you should call the function and check if the return value equals "8.17.0" during *configuration* time. If yes, then the `node` binary is of version 8.17.0, otherwise, the node binary is of a different version (or perhaps node is missing).

Comment: ya this worked out for me. Thanks. 1 more thing is there anything else that we can do to compare the versions. Lets say I want 8.17.0 in my project and installed version is 1.2.3 (lower version). In this case I want to download the required version. So how can I compare without writing java/groovy logic.

Comment: If the node is not installed and above code is ran we get error in console: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ui-service'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'node''

Comment: You can use similar code to run `which node` to check if the node binary exists before running `node -v`. For comparing the versions you have to write some Java/Groovy logic (or depend on some third-party code that does this for you).